# Python Dash TypeError: cannot convert 'NoneType' object to bytes

Tags: python, dashboard, plotly-dash

I am trying to build a dashboard using Dash. I keep getting this error when I go to the default website http://127.0.0.1:8050/ and I get  TypeError: cannot convert 'NoneType' object. Check the image for the error. My code does not have any mistakes and I was able to run it before and the dashboard would work perfectly. Can someone please help me? Here is the code:

```
import dash  # (version 1.12.0) pip install dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import datetime
from datetime import date


app = dash.Dash(__name__)

# App layout
app.layout = html.Div([

    html.H1("Snodas SWE/SD For January", style={'text-align': 'center'}),

    
    dcc.DatePickerSingle(
        id='my-date-picker-single',
        min_date_allowed=date(2020, 1, 1),
        max_date_allowed=date(2020, 12, 30),
        initial_visible_month=date(2020, 1, 1),
        date=date(2020, 1, 1)
    ),
    
    html.Div(id='output-container-date-picker-single'),
    
    dcc.Checklist(
    options=[
        {'label': 'SWE', 'value': 'SWE'},
        {'label': 'SD', 'value': 'SD'}
    ],
    labelStyle={'display': 'inline-block'}
    ),

    html.Iframe(id='map', srcDoc=open('map1.html', 'r').read(), width='100%', height='1000')

])

@app.callback(
    Output('map', 'srcDoc'),
    Input('my-date-picker-single', 'date'))
def update_output(date):
    return open('map_swe_sd_{}.html'.format(str(date)), 'r').read()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run_server(debug = True)
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQbtX.png)

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: As the error message (which you've already looked up, right?) tells you, you're trying to convert something to `bytes` format, but that something is `None`.  Since you didn't include the *entire* error message, we don't know what that something is, how it got to be `None`, and how you think you guaranteed otherwise.

Comment: We expect you to perform basic diagnosis to include with your post.  At the very least, print the offending values at the point of error and trace them back to their sources.
In many cases, doing this basic diagnosis will show you where the problem lies, and you won't need Stack Overflow at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
@app.callback(
    Output('map', 'srcDoc'),
    Input('my-date-picker-single', 'date'))
def update_output(date):
    if not date:
        raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate
    return open('map_swe_sd_{}.html'.format(str(date)), 'r').read()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to all of this, so I hope I do this right and according to the conventional rules:

I had the same problem when I simply tried to do the dash tutorial on the dash website.

There was something wrong with my installation of dash or with my python environment (I know that "something wrong is not really an identification of the problem). It seems like this is similar in your case since the tracebacks point to packages, right? After creating and activating a new python environment, and installing dash there, everything worked.

I hope this might help you as well.